# Dart editor. How to use sub folders

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I had a large working Dart web-app until yesterday, when I did a pub upgrade. The editor reports no problems in my code, but in the `index.html` window when I run, I get about 20 errors:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
     http://localhost:8080/interface%5Ct_file.dart
     An error occurred loading file: http://localhost:8080/interface%5Ct_file.dart

-one for each of my polymer templates (like t_file.dart), which are in folder "web/interface". 
 After hours trying to fix it, I created a **new** polymer app from scratch. I create a template called t_file. It works fine when t_file is in folder web, but if I restructure and move t_file to subfolder **web/interface**, I cannot get the progam to run. There are no complaints in the editor, but I get the above error on running. A blank webpage appears.
 Is the replacement of the slash character to %5C expected? Is that the problem? 
 cheers, Steve

Comment: I added the [:dart:] tag for better visibility. What Dart and Polymer version are you using? Have you tried `pub cache repair`, and/or deleting the `.pub`, `.pub.cache` folder? I have seen a similar error but I can't remember where and not find anything about it anymore.

Comment: I have a similar problem since I upgraded to the current versions of polymer, core-elements and paper-elements. I have removed all .pub folders, .dartium, pub folder all packages and still the index.html fails give the 404 error - Build error:
Transform polymer (PolymerBootstrapTransformer) on polymer_snippet|web/index.html threw error: Bad state: No element. There are several other lines ending with Build completed with 1 errors.
[web] GET /index.html => Could not find asset polymer_snippet|web/index.html.
[web] GET /favicon.ico => polymer_snippet|web/favicon.ico. The index.html is present.

Comment: Please create a bug report at https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart